# Angular-leaflet: How to add multiple geojson from ajax response

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm trying to dynamically add multiple GeoJSON data to my map. as shown below. However I don't see the data getting rendered.

```
$http.get("/kp-data").success(function(data, status){

                angular.forEach(data, function(k,v){
                        $scope.geojson[k.carId] = {data : k.data,
                                resetStyleOnMouseout: true,
                                style: {
                                    fillColor: k.color,
                                    weight: 2,
                                    opacity: 1,
                                    color: 'white',
                                    dashArray: '3',
                                    fillOpacity: 0.7
                                }
                        }
                });
```

In this [example](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0000-viewer.html#/basic/geojson-nested-example) the geojson data USA and JPN is hardcoded. I modified the code for dynamic addition. The code works if I modified as below for a single geojson data

```
   $http.get("/kp-data").success(function(data, status){

            angular.forEach(data, function(k,v){
                    if(v==1){
                    $scope.geojson = {data : k.data,
                            resetStyleOnMouseout: true,
                            style: {
                                fillColor: k.color,
                                weight: 2,
                                opacity: 1,
                                color: 'white',
                                dashArray: '3',
                                fillOpacity: 0.7
                            }
                    }
                 }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some error message ?

And you should declear `$scope.geojson` as an object before you call `angular.forEach` function.

like [this](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/blob/1cfbdf4a7f68bfddddc7472b5799c7b950337b2a/examples/0307-paths-events-example-with-id.html#L14) .

Comment: yes I've declared the variable, else the second case would not  have worked

Answer (score 0):

After declare $scope.jeojson = [], length of this is 0, so in loop $scope.jeojson[index] is undefined (index # 0). I think you should try something as: $scope.jeojson.push(json)...

And, i recommend you to use "for" rather than "angular.forEach". Hope it good for you!